# Flickr OAuth authentication

Tags: authentication, matlab, flickr

I would like to test the Flickr API using Matlab. There is no Flickr API library available for Matlab, so I have to do everything myself.

I am having troubles pretty much in the beginning: cannot cope with authentication. The process description is here: http://www.flickr.com/services/api/auth.oauth.html. However, I do not understand a couple of things in Signing Requests:

First,

```
the key is the concatenated values of the Consumer Secret 
and Token Secret, separated by an '&'.
```

What are the Consumer Secret and the Token Secret? I only have the API key and API secret, issued for my test application by Flickr.

Second, the result of signing a string (which should be the output of the HMAC SHA1 function, i.e. a number, right?) in the example is `w18YS2bONDPL%2FzgyzP5XTr5af4%3D`. What is it? It is neither a hex number nor a base64 string.

Comment: I think I have found the answers to these two questions (sorry, I should have posted the question first to suddenly find the answer; but I spent the whole day before). The Consumer Secret is the secret key of the application, provided by Flickr. The Token Secret is not available at the initial stage, so should be left out. The strange string actually _is_ a base64 string, but url-safe-encoded. I will try again and post the result/new questions here.

Comment: Well, I was able to solve the problems with signing, however I still cannot force flickr to accept the very first token request. Matlab shows `Error downloading URL. Your network connection may be down or your proxy settings improperly configured` however breakstopping the urlread function reveals errors 401 and 403, so there is something happening in fact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this task. The answer I put in the form of a short tutorial to Matlab file exchange: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34162. I will also keep a list of additional hints in my blog http://texnical.wordpress.com/2011/12/12/flickr-api-with-user-authentication-in-matlab/.

I'd like to acknowledge the help of Sam Judson from the [Flickr API discussion list](http://www.flickr.com/groups/api/discuss/).

Answer (score 1):

You might find it easier to build an interface from MATLAB to one of the available [Flickr API kits](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/). MATLAB makes it particularly easy to call C, Java and perl, so those might be a good choice.

Comment: Well, I actually wanted to implement the whole thing in Matlab. Consider it as an exercise if you like. So I don't need it to be easy.

Comment: OK - good luck. If you'd be willing, when you've finished it would be great if you could post your experiences. I've tried and failed to do something similar (the Notifo API rather than Flickr) in pure MATLAB, and I had to resort to calling other languages.